# Looping between 2 Workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, loops

So what I want to do is

- WS2 Has different names which are used as the reference sheet
- Based on each name in the WS2 column, count how many times it is repeated in the WS1 column.
- Put count in WS2 another column (5)

This means that it will loop the WS1 Column with each different row of the names in WS2

To further visualize what I'm trynna do.

WS1 Would be something like this

```
C1 Names  
C2 Bob   
C3 Tom    
C4 LEE 
C5 LEE 
C6 Bob 
C7 Sam 
C8 LEE 
C9 Bob 
C10 Tom
```

WS2 would be the name to collate

```
A1 Names       E1 Sum  
A2 Bob         E2  3 
A3 Tom         E3  2 
A4 LEE         E4  3 
A5 Sam         E5  1
```

My current code

```vb
Sub closed()
    Dim WS1 As Worksheet
    Dim WS2 As Worksheet
    Set WS1 = Workbooks("Close").Worksheets("Sheet 1")
    Set WS2 = Workbooks("Usernames").Worksheets("Sheet 2")
    
    Dim Rng1 As Range
    Dim Rng2 As Range
    Set Rng1 = WS1.Range("C2:C" & LastRow1)
    Set Rng2 = WS2.Range("A2:A" & LastRow2)
   
    Dim LastRow1, LastRow2 As Integer
    LastRow1 = WS1.Cells(WS1.Rows.count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    LastRow2 = WS2.Cells(WS2.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim col As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer, str As String
    Dim count As Integer
    
    count = 0
         
        j = 2
         
        Do While j <= LastRow2
        
            str = WS2.Cells(j, 1)
        
            count = WS2.Cells(j, 5).Value
        
            count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Rng1, str)

        j = j + 1
        Loop
        
        
 End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm, so what is your question? Do you experience unexpected behavior? What? Did you step through the code to find out where it doesn't do what you want it to??

Comment: You're trying to use `LastRow1` and `LastRow2` before you've assigned any value to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As Tim Williams rightly pointed out, before you assign variables they should be defined & values should be calculated first.
2. I saw your code was calculating results through "countif" formula but
   was not storing a result.
3. You only need a below simple loop logic after creating a helper variable "Dim Cel as range"

For Each Cel In Rng2
Cel.Offset(0, 4).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Rng1, Cel.Value)
Next Cel

Finally, your code should look something like below.

```
Sub Generate_Colsed_Username_Count()
    Dim Ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim Ws2 As Worksheet
    Set Ws1 = Workbooks("Close").Worksheets("Sheet 1")
    Set Ws2 = Workbooks("Usernames").Worksheets("Sheet 2")

    Dim LastRow1, LastRow2 As Integer
    LastRow1 = Ws1.Cells(Ws1.Rows.count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    LastRow2 = Ws2.Cells(Ws2.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
    Dim Rng1 As Range
    Dim Rng2 As Range
    Dim Cel As Range
    Set Rng1 = Ws1.Range("C2:C" & LastRow1)
    Set Rng2 = Ws2.Range("A2:A" & LastRow2)
    
    For Each Cel In Rng2
        Cel.Offset(0, 4).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Rng1, Cel.Value)
    Next Cel
    
    MsgBox "Task Completed"
    
End Sub
```

Please, share feedback after testing it.

If something is not clear enough, do not hesitate to ask for clarification.

Comment: Yep this code works exactly how I wanted it to, thanks!